# Angular authorization(?) failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview) solution of authorization problem. However, when I click the submit button of the form, the function I specified in `ng-submit` parameter of the form is not called and console log says:

```
Error: args is null
$parseFunctionCall@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:12405:1
ngEventHandler/</callback@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:21566:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:14466:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:14565:18
ngEventHandler/<@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:21571:17
m.event.dispatch@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3:8384
m.event.add/r.handle@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3:5122
```

What does this mean? And how can I fix it? Before I tried to use cookies everything seemed to work fine and the function was called.

Answer (score 0):

For some unbelievable reason changing the name of `ng-submit` function from *login* to *submit* resolved this issue oO